# Get the address of the element in a vector

Tags: c++

Suppose I need this be done

I have a function, such as:

```
int dbs_access(chat* name, char* sql, void* outbuf, unsigned int buflen, int* outresutl)
{ do some query here and output result}
```

I want to get some data from DBS, so I need get some buffer and call the function above, since I don't know how many records in tables, so I can't use array, I don't want want to use new or malloc to get some memory either, because releasing memory could be a problem here. Therefore I want to use vector. But I am not sure this would be guaranteed by c++ standard ,any view?

```
unsigned int count;

dbs_access(...,"select count(*) from..",&count,sizeof(count),...)
std::vector records[count];
assert(records.size()==count)
dbs_access(...,"select from..",&records[0],records.size(),...)
```

Comment: You'll probably want `std::vector<char>` there - you need to give it a type, and for flexibility for UTF16 characters, etc, `records.size()*sizeof(records[0])`, as `size()` gives the number of elements, not the total size.

Comment: You are right, that is a error.

Comment: a side note: if the number of records is very large the above approach using a vector may cause you problems since a vector is guaranteed to be in a continuous block. in that case maybe a list or deque would be a better choice. disclaimer: without knowing exactly your requirements & constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

records.data() will give you the pointer, and yes it's acceptable to use vector here, although you might want to initialise the size like so:

```
 std::vector records(count);
```

(Rather than creating an array of vectors)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  stop the press! I failed to notice that you probably don't want `&records[0]`. That doesn't do what I thought it did because I didn't notice this line:

```
std::vector records[count];
```

That line is probably not what you want anyway, so change it to this instead:

```
std::vector records(count);
```

and then you will have what you likely actually want, and my below answer will apply again.

---

`std::vector` [stores data in a continuous space after C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22013788/10957435):

> From the n2798 (draft of C++0x)::
>
> > 23.2.6 Class template vector [vector]
> >
> > 1 A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and >>erase in the middle take linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some type other than bool, then it >>obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().

So, something like `&records[0]` should be okay, although some consider it not the best. `std::vector::data()` (or `records.data()` in your case) is usually preferred, as long as you are in C++11 or greater.