# Create a pointer to an element in a vector<vector<bool>>

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, boolean

If I want a pointer to an element in a vector of vectors of int, I write:

```
vector<vector<int>> a (5);
int* p1 = a[4].data();
```

However, it doesn't work with a vector of vectors of bool (why?) when I write:

```
vector<vector<bool>> b(5);
bool* p2 = b[4].data();
```

The compiler outputs the following error message:

```
Semantic issue: Error: Cannot initialize a variable of type "bool*" with an rvalue of type "void".
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: tl;dr - `std::vector<bool>` is special and weird.

Comment: [`std::vector<bool>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) doesn't have a `data` method.

Comment: It's highly unlikely you want to use vector <bool> at all. If you do want to take the addresses of things in the container, use a std::deque<bool>, or a std::vector<char>..

Comment: [Don't forget that pointers to `vector` elements can easily be invalidated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: `int* p1 = a[4].data();` "Works" but probably not the way you think. `a[4].data()` is not pointer to an actual int because `a[4]` and all the other objects of the top vector are an empty vector of ints. to put something (43) into it you would use `std::a[4].push_back(42);` Then `*a[4].data() == 42` and you can also access it like so: `a[4][0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` unfortunately is a specialization that may save space by using just a bit for each element. This is not guaranteed but can happen.

When this happens it means that using pointers to element is not possible (the minimum size of an object in C++ is one byte) and also a lot of other specifics of `std::vector` do not work for `std::vector<bool>`.

Just don't use it... if you need bit packing implement it yourself (at least you know what you get in a portable way) and if you don't care about the bit vs byte saving just use an `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead (that is a real `std::vector`).

`std::vector<bool>` specialization was basically a mistake of C++, it has no meaningful use. Doesn't provide any **guaranteed** advantage and may create problems in the future (for example even for code that currently doesn't need proper standard iterators now, may be the code will need to evolve into needing them, and if you used `vector<bool>` then you're doomed).

Comment: It has plenty meaningful use if you don't need the features that aren't available as a result. Too much fearmongering here.

Comment: Or `struct bool_wrapper { bool value; };` and `std::vector<bool_wrapper>` which requires a bit of packing and unpacking.  (Puns intended.)

Comment: I tend to agree on the "fearmongering" comment.   `vector<bool>` is fine, as long as it is used within its defined limits.   You can't blame the type for programmers who try to shoe-horn it into usage patterns it isn't suited for, and then complain when it doesn't work as expected.     Trying to get the address of something that might be packed within a byte (the smallest addressable unit) is actually the problem, in this case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the problem is that people don't expect `std::vector<bool>` to be something different from an `std::vector` of `bool`. If C++ wanted to provide a container of "bits" then it should have provided one (and guarantee/methods about how to handle it... for example do you know how to serialize efficiently an `std::vector<bool>`? ... you can't... you must iterate over all bits). `std::vector<bool>` is a mistake and should not been used (there have been even discussion about how to get rid of it, see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1211.pdf).

Comment: @6502 I'm aware of all that, but the fact remains that if you _do_ know what `std::vector<bool>` is then you can make use of it just fine. It has plenty of "meaningful use".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit never seen it used, and I doubt anybody would who knows what it really is. Only usage I've seen by mistake from people expecting it to work like regular vector.

Comment: @Slava I use it on occasion