# Why does &vector_char[0] print all characters?

Tags: c++

I have been analyzing code and I came across this:

```
...
vector <char> buffer (size + 1);
vsnprintf (& buffer [0], buffer.size (), format, args);
printf (& buffer [0]);
...
```

So I was wondering why it prints all the characters and in the vnsprinft function, the reference to the first element of the vector is passed

Comment: You are passing the **address of** the first character, not a *reference* to it.

Comment: The `&` symbol has multiple meanings in C++.  You're mistaken that in this context, it means *reference*.  No, it means *address-of*.

Comment: What did you expect  it to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as others have mentioned, this is due to the fact that you are not actually passing by reference, you're actually passing the address. This is because the `&` has different meanings in different contexts.

In a function declaration context, it means passing by reference:

```
void myFunc(int& i) { // << pass by reference
    std::cout << i;
}
```

When you call such a function, you don't need the `&`:

```
int main () {
    int i = 3;

    myFunc(i); // << still passing by reference even though you aren't using the & here


    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, using an `&` when you **call** a function means taking an address of that variable. It's just like doing this:

```
int main () {
    int i = 3;
    int * ptr = &i; // gets the address of i


    return 0;
}
```

Here, we're getting a pointer to `i`, not getting a reference to it.

It's the same for functions. Here is a function example:

```
void myFunc(int* i) { // << passing the address of a variable
    if(i != nullptr) {
        std::cout << *i;
    }
}
int main () {
    int i = 3;

    myFunc(&i); // << Now we're passing the address of i


    return 0;
}
```

So that's the first part of what's going on.

---

So, why does this result in printing all the characters? Well, you're basically running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17813423/10957435), just with a few layers between you and the character pointer. As mentioned in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813845/10957435), `char *`s are an old way of representing strings. Thus, a lot of functions treat `char*` as a string, not a single character.

So, how are you getting a `char *` from an `std::vector`? Well, suffice it to say you're doing it accidentally by using the `&`. Since [`std::vector`s have continuous memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22013697/10957435), you basically end up with a valid `char *`.